# how to show 404 page in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to show the 404 pages in laravel 5.2 projects. but how is possible and how to handle errors in laravel 5.2?
please help me!

1. how to handle errors in laravel 5.2?
2. how to return 404 page?
3. if cannot find URL then return 404 page in laravel 5.2?

Answer (score 1):

Just  use `abort(404, 'Not Found');` in your code.

---

Consider the [Laravel 5.2 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#http-exceptions) on how this works:

> Some exceptions describe HTTP error codes from the server. For example, this may be a "page not found" error (404), an "unauthorized error" (401) or even a developer generated 500 error. In order to generate such a response from anywhere in your application, use the following:
>
> ```php
> abort(404);
> ```
>
> The `abort` method will immediately raise an exception which will be rendered by the exception handler. Optionally, you may provide the response text:
>
> ```php
> abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
> ```
>
> This method may be used at any time during the request's lifecycle.